Can only reach the Flask App with GET but not with POST
I am using Python Flask (Import) as an API to receive json files with Keycloak for validation. At the same there is also a Vue App and a second python flask app (backend), which works perfectly.
Everything is setup with NGINX, when I try to execute a GET request to the IMPORT Service I get a 200 response so the URL is reachable. But with a POST request I get an 405 Error although I get an access token successfully from Keycloak. Where is the problem?
I am not sure whether the flask app or the NGINX is the problem here the code:
#Python app
require_auth = ResourceProtector()
validator = ClientCredsTokenValidator("https://myEndpoint/energy/data")
require_auth.register_token_validator(validator)

@app.route('/energy/data', methods=['POST'])
@require_auth("energy_data")
def energy_data_api():
    data =request.json
    print(request.headers)
    
    #res = add_new_data(data, 'add-energy-data') ####DB Entry

    response = "JSON ARRIVED"
    print(response)

    return jsonify(message=response), 200


#NGINX.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.domain;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

upstream backend {
   server my.domainIP:5000;
}

upstream import {
   server my.domainIP:5001;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my.domain;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
    }
    location /getUser {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass backend;
    }
    location /action {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass backend;
    }
    location /energy/data {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass import;
    }
    location /masterData/update {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass import;
    }
}



@app.route('/energy/data', methods=['GET']) - you have configured it to only accept GET requests...

It is pretty logical to accept only GET requests as you literally tell it "This request is GET-only". You do this in this line:
@app.route('/energy/data', methods=['GET'])

If you want it to be able to make a POST request too you should modify it such as so:
@app.route('/energy/data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

Hope this helps you.

Sorry I wrote it wrong, I used methods=['POST'] and still get 405 error.

Hmm I see, This is tougher then. I wanna try to isolate the problem. Can you please try to execute your web-app without nginx? I mean with a different server like apache etc.?

I added the endpoint into the backend service which runs on Port 5000, it works here with POST request. As a workaround it is ok but the endpoint should be an own flask service.
